# Math model for Bank Savings using programming

Tags: functions, programming

```
 Starting conditions:
    -------------------
       Age: 327 months (27 years, 3 months)
       Savings: $21,345
```

Write a function which computes earned sum after each month

```
Working:
 --------
  Months: 489
  Per Month Savings: $1000
  Rate of Return:  4.5% per year ( 0.045/12 per month) 
                   [above inflation]
```

I need to find out how many dollars after 489 months knowing that now I am 327 months old and my current savings are $21345.

I managed to solve this problem using geometric progression, and of course using powers. But now, I would like to compute without using powers. I would like to use a function, like in programming. 
Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Comment: Strictly speaking, if the yearly interest is $4.5~\%$, the montly interest is not $\frac{0.045}{12} \approx 0.38$ but $\sqrt[12]{1.045} \approx 0.37~\%$. At least it should be, it probably depends on the bank etc.

Comment: If you already managed to solve it (using geometric progression), what's the problem? You apparently have the equation, so just use it! Also, why do you want to compute it without using powers? You kinda have to use powers, because there is only one equation to correctly calculate it, and it definitely uses powers. Of course you could create some iterative scheme ...

Comment: @MattiP. the interest is indeed $\frac{0.045}{12} $

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double currentSavings= 21345,currentAge= 327,futureAge  = 489,
    periodicPayment = 1000;
    double annumInterest = (4.5/100);

    double monthlyInt = annumInterest/12;
    double total = currentSavings;
    for(double i = currentAge; i<futureAge; i++)
    {
        total *= (1+monthlyInt);
        total += periodicPayment;
    }

    //if you want to add rounding:

    total *= 100;
    total = Math.round(total);
    total /= 100;
    System.out.println(" $ "+ total);
}
```

Output: $ 261475.11